# Downcast error in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode7, downcast

In xcode 6, this code worked fine, but in Xcode 7GM, I am getting an error that states:

> Downcast from ‘[UILocalNotification]? to ‘[UILocalNotification]’ only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use ‘!’?

The error occurs for the line where I have put two asterisks. In Xcode, there is also a little red triangle under the `a` of the `as!` portion.

```
func removeItem(item: TodoItem) {
    **for notification in (UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications as! [UILocalNotification]) { // loop through notifications...
        if (notification.userInfo!["UUID"] as! String == item.UUID) { // ...and cancel the notification that corresponds to this TodoItem instance (matched by UUID)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification) // there should be a maximum of one match on UUID
            break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode 6 `scheduledLocalNotifications` is declared as `[AnyObject]!` (downcast required).
In Xcode 7 `scheduledLocalNotifications` is declared as `[UILocalNotification]?` (has only to be unwrapped)

I recommend to use optional bindings

```
func removeItem(item: TodoItem) {
  if let scheduledLocalNotifications = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications {
   for notification in scheduledLocalNotifications { // loop through notifications...
    if (notification.userInfo!["UUID"] as! String == item.UUID) { // ...and cancel the notification that corresponds to this TodoItem instance (matched by UUID)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification) // there should be a maximum of one match on UUID
        break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much!